# Cash-flow forecasting in excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, calendar

I would like it to be able to input contract details (name of the client, duration of the contract and total yearly amount ). Using these contract details, I would like for the program or template to populate a calendar in which we can see each day's deposits.

For example: If I entered 2 contracts:

1. Total yearly amount of 120$ that start on 01/01/2019
2. Total yearly amount of 180$ that start on 01/03/2019

by choosing to view **March** calendar, I would see on the 01/03/2019 2 deposits one of 10$ and the other of 15$ for a total of 25$. But, If I choose to view the month of **February**, I would see on 01/02/2019 1 deposit of 10$.

I have started an excel sheet which populates it perfectly if it is one time deposit for a specific date.

Where I got stuck was for **monthly deposits** and **special deposits** (*special conditions where the first month required 25% of the total yearly amount, and will complete the remainder 75% of the total yearly amount in 5 equal deposit the following months)*.

Here is my basic formula I have put on each day for the month of Janurary:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(Inputs!$D3,2))=B$2,(VALUE(MID(Inputs!$D3,4,2))='C.F. JAN'!$B$1)),IF(Inputs!$C3="Fixed Monthly",Inputs!$G3/12,IF(Inputs!$C3="Yearly",Inputs!$G3,"")),""),"")
```

Here is the one of Februrary:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(Inputs!$D3,2))=C$2,(VALUE(MID(Inputs!$D3,4,2))='C.F. FEB'!$B$1)),IF(Inputs!$C3="Fixed Monthly",Inputs!$G3/12,IF(Inputs!$C3="Yearly",Inputs!$G3,"")),""),"")
```

I have created sheets for each month that sum the amounts each client's appropriate deposit.

@jessi here is how my data looks like:

[image]

here is the formula on M3:

```
=SUMIF($D$3:$D$10000,$L3,$H$3:$H$10000)+SUMIFS($I$3:$I$10000,$D$3:$D$10000,"<"&$L3,$J$3:$J$10000,">="&$L3)
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Your examples do not have the specials, but you can set them up. For example, your "Contracts" worksheet or Range could have the Fields: StartDate, Total, First, Installments. Then, you could say, "IF(there is something in First)...handle differently" and "IF(there is something in installments)...divide some other way. It may be easier to handle something like this with vba.

Comment: @jessi Great idea, I figured that the if statements I will need to add would be endless. I think what I needed to do is something like (If the month is 01, then add the amount/12 to 02,03,04,05 etc,) and then another if for 02, add to 03,04,05). Do you see any other options?

Comment: @jessi Yes I agree with you that vba might be much easier, I have unfortunately very limited knowledge of VBA coding :S

Comment: @ScottCraner I have edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can do some preliminary math so that your if statements are very simple.

Here's an example. see the added columns? You could enter the data for Contract, Value, Start, First, and Installments. Calculations for FirstPayment, NormalPayment, and Stop.

[image]

FirstPayment, for contract a, Row 2, calculated as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),G2,D2*B2)
```

NormalPayment for contract a, Row 2, calculated as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),B2/E2,(1-D2)*B2/E2)
```

Stop for contract a, Row 2 calculated as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),EDATE(C2,E2),EDATE(C2,E2+1))
```

Then, the months with their payments expected, look like so (the formula for January shown):
NOTE: the date 2019-01-01 is in A7, the result (where this formula goes) is in A8. Copy and paste for rest of columns.

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$4,$A7,$F$2:$F$4)+SUMIFS($G$2:G$4,$C$2:$C$4,"<"&$A7,$H$2:$H$4,">="&$A7)
```

Note that the first SUMIF is dealing with anything that is in its first month. The SUMIFs is dealing with anything that is between Start and Stop.

Edit for changed question to show cashflow by day
To show by day, you first need to add another column, let's say column I, to the data table for contracts. This is the DAY column. `DAY($C2)`. To keep things simple for your cashflow, actually make this `If(day($C2)>28),1,day($C2))` to make any falls on 29, 30, or 31 to show up on the next first. You can make other choices here.

[image: new contract tab]

Then, you can have each day in time in your cashflow sheet.

I put the cashflow on a new tab and named the contracts data tab CONTRACTS

[image: cashflow]

The cashflow formula (with date in $A2 and result in $B2) is:

```
=SUMIF(CONTRACTS!$C$2:$C$5,$A2,CONTRACTS!$F$2:$F$5)+SUMIFS(CONTRACTS!$G$2:G$5,CONTRACTS!$C$2:$C$5,"<"&$A2,CONTRACTS!$H$2:$H$5,">="&$A2,CONTRACTS!$I$2:$I$5,DAY(A2))
```

Comment: Will try this right now thanks! will update as soon as I complete it.

Comment: @jerri, So I have now played with this for a while and added the possibility to have not only the monthly deposits list but the daily too. on A7 I wrote 01/01/2019, then on A8 I wrote 02/01/2019 and dragged it until end of 2020 (total of 730 lines). If I use the same formula on 02/02/2019, I get a result instead of 0$. So that leads me to believe the formula is considering the month and year but not the day. Any idea how I can include the day as well so that in this example it would show 0$ for 02/02/2019 and so on?

Comment: @jerri Nevermind! I found the issue, $A1 represents a blank cell and when I would drag the formula it would drop it to  $A2, I added a $ and it worked perfectly. Thank again jessi

Comment: woops, for some reason I can't get it to work. It is or putting the amount on the correct dates and every day after it, or it is putting the amount on the correct date but not the subsequent months later.

Comment: Ok. I don't think I understand your problem. Can you update your question with a data set that looks like what you have in trying to implement this solution?

Comment: Added a picture to best represent the current result including the formula. Thanks :)

Comment: So, the problem is that you want to see the payment on each date and not for each month? If that is the case, you can change the formula. Instead of a if < and > you can check that the day is the same. Or just make it every 30 days. If you try to do each day, you have to deal with the 29,30,31 that do not occur every month.

Comment: your are exactly right. I was suggested to insert a column on H with the formula: =DAY(column of the start day) and then modified the formula you have given to this: `=SUMIF(Contrats!$D$3:$D$10000,$L3,Contrats!$I$3:$I$10000)+SUMIFS(Contrats!$J$3:J$10000,Contrats!$D$3:$D$10000,"<"&$L3,Contrats!$K$3:$K$10000,">="&$a2,Contrats!$H$3:$H$10000,DAY($L3))`

Comment: L3 is where 01/01/2019 and continues to 31/12/2020.

Comment: tried it and it works!. I see that the key was to add the day column and reference it in the formula. Thank you so much!